# ActiveX Control on Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, osx-mountain-lion, activex

I am trying to render a page that requires ActiveX. 
Everything is done locally, so the device I am trying to access by IP is on my local network. Anyway, the error I am getting on my Mac, (using Chrome/Firefox/Safari) is this message:

```
ActiveX control failed to load (OCX)-- Please check browser security settings.
```

The weird thing is that it works on a Windows 7 machine using I.E if I disable all the security settings.

Is there anyway to disable security settings on Firefox or Chrome or Safari on OSX Mountain Lion, so ActiveX does not give me that error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the ActiveX control would have to be coded specifically to target Macs, and would need to run using the limited ActiveX support in IE Mac (no other Mac browser ever has or likely will support this proprietary MS technology, despite the misleading security error thrown). Since Microsoft has long ago discontinued the Mac version of their browser, I highly doubt you will ever get the control to work, even if a Mac version is available (which I doubt is the case). As for it working in IE on Win7, what's so weird about that?